# Display a list of objects with properties in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have the following code from my React component:

```
        <div className="mainApp">
            <div className="pkgsList">
                {pkgData.map((p) => 
                    <h3 key={p.name}>{p.name}</h3>                    
                )}
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

In this case, `pkgData` is an array of objects which try to describe a package in this scenario. Each object contains a string propery `name` and an array property `sources` for which every item is also an object. I'd like to print the items inside `sources` (a couple properties for each item) underneath my `h3` element as above, but I can't seem to figure out how to add more HTML / JSX on what I have above - any help would be appreciated.

I keep trying to call map for each p but keep running into an error whether I wrap it on `()` or just `{}` e.g.

```
{p.map((s) => {
                       
})
```

So the resulting div code would be:

```
            <div className="pkgList">
                {pkgData.map((p) => 
                    <h3 key={p.name}>{p.name}</h3>
                    {p.map((c) => {
                        
                    })
                )}
            </div>
```

does not let my react app compile successfully.

Comment: *"but I can't seem to figure out how to add more HTML / JSX"* - Have you tried?  What didn't work as expected?

Comment: *"and an array property sources [...] `p.map`*" - If `p.sources` is the array then you'd want to call `.map()` on `p.sources`.  It sounds like this is just a typo.  (Or potentially a misunderstanding of the difference between an object and an array, or a misunderstanding of the data structure you're trying to use.  All of which I'd still essentially categorize as a "typo".)

Comment: `p` isn't an array though right? Wouldn't you want `p.sources.map`?

Comment: The error seems to be using { after the closing > from h3 element, showing this: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: Looks like maybe there's a syntax error in the mix too with {} not closing correctly

Comment: @user1397215: In JSX you can't have two top-level elements.  Wrap the `<h3>` and the `{p.sources.map()}` segments in a React fragment or other HTML element.

Comment: @user1397215 as a rule, anytime a question says something like "I'm getting an error" the error message should always be included in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Wrong map

First, your nested map inside of `pkgData.map` is wrong.
Because `p` itself isn't array.
The map should be like this,

```
{p.sources.map((c) => {
    ...
    }
  )}
```

## Wrong JSX

Second, like @David said in the comment, you can't have more than one top-level elements because of the way JSX works under the hood.
For example, the code

```
<div className="mainApp">
  <div className="pkgsList">
    {pkgData.map((p) => 
      <h3 key={p.name}>{p.name}</h3>                    
    )}
  </div>
</div>
```

is equivalent to this

```
<div className="mainApp">
  <div className="pkgsList">
    {pkgData.map((p) => {
      return React.createElement("h3", {key: p.name}, p.name)
      }                    
    )}
  </div>
</div>
```

So if you return more than one JSX elements at the top level, React.createElement cannot work.
Therefore you should wrap the things up on the top level with some tags like fragments(<>), div, etc.

For example,

```
<div className="mainApp">
  <div className="pkgsList">
    {pkgData.map((p) =>
      <>
        <h3 key={p.name}>{p.name}</h3>
        {p.sources.map((c) => 
          <p>{c.something}</p>
        )} 
      </>
    )}
  </div>
</div>
```

FYI: https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement#creating-an-element-without-jsx

Answer (score 2):

You can only return 1 jsx element in map like in a normal component. If you want to render multiple elements in the map function you can wrap the the code in a react fragment like so:

```
<div className="mainApp">
    <div className="pkgsList">
        {pkgData.map((p) => (
            <> {/* <- this is a fragment */}
                <h3 key={p.name}>{p.name}</h3>
                {p.sources.map((s) => (
                    <>{/* render source here */}</>
                ))}
            </>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>
```